# Bootstrap slides in impress.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, impress.js

I'm looking for a way to enable the *Bootstrap* style for certain slides in an *impress.js* presentation. I've tried to do this by adding the `bootstrapslide` style to these slides and compiling Boostrap Less such that it is applied only to these `div` items with that style. However the slides show little of the Boostrap Style.

This is probably because `impress.js` first empties all styles (`h1`, `pre`,...) and that bootstrap adds some attributes, but fails to make the changes visible. I have however no immediate solution to this problem.

**Minimal Working Example**:

**`presentation.htm`:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="http://netdna.impressjscdn.com/impressjs/0.5.3/css/impress-demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- custom.css -->
  <link href="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dTdEky6N" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="impress">
    <div id="title" class="step" data-x="0" data-y="0" data-scale="4">
      <h1><center>Presentation</center></h1>
      <span><center>November 30, 2014</center></span>
    </div>
    <div id="slide0" class="step slide bootstrapslide" data-x="1800" data-y="0">
      <h1>Title1</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="slide1" class="step slide bootstrapslide" data-x="3600" data-y="0">
      <h1>Title2</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.impressjscdn.com/impressjs/0.5.3/js/impress.js"></script>
  <script>
    impress().init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**`custom.css`** is compiled from `custom.css` and the Bootstrap Less package:

**`custom.less`**

```
div.bootstrapslide {
    @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the bootstrap.less?

Comment: That is simply the `bootstrap.less` file, one can download (for instance on GitHub) https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less

Comment: I tried to convert your example code into a code snippet. The issue might be that the custom.css as created by the less compiler isn't valid css making the browsers css parser simply give up. If you take a look at the custom.css in http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dTdEky6N you'll notice invalid html elements as `trdiv` occurring.

Comment: Actually if I try it on a local webserver, it simply works. I've added a `.btn .btn-primary` button the the first sheet and I do see bootstraps styling. Isn't it also an issue of Bootstrap setting a lot of the default styling on the `html` and `body` elements? These won't be applied in your case as they'll occur as `div.bootstrapslide html` and `div.bootstrapslide body` and never match any element.

If this is simply about your own presentation you might take a look at scoped css (http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) and use Firefox (http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped)

Answer (score 1):

Your import is in the wrong place.

You are importing **all** your bootstrap code into `div.bootstrapslide`. Instead, you could do one of two things:

Copy the relevant bootstrap code directly into your class:

```
div.bootstrapslide {
    // boostrapslide CSS here
}
```

or just import it at the beginning of the file and use the native bootstrap class:

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
// your CSS here
```

Comment: But the bootstrap code should be in the `div.bootstrapslide`. There is no extra css code. The `bootstrapslide` elements should be handled as if they are minipages in bootstrap style.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you. But I thought that the content of your bootstrap.less was the one that you linked to, so: `// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
...`
Is that right?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Because it's basically the same point that ckuijjer is making, and apparently it works for him.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete these lines? It worked for me.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```